# Differences between XML string encoding in MRI and JRuby

Tags: jruby

I'd like to use JRuby to create some XML files, but it is not escaping characters in the same way MRI Ruby does.

```
> "<node attr=#{'this is "my" complicated <String>'.encode(:xml => :attr)} />"
```

MRI

```
  ruby-1.9.3-p194 
  => "<node attr=\"this is &quot;my&quot; complicated &lt;String&gt;\" />"
```

JRuby

```
  jruby-1.7.2 
  => "<node attr=this is \"my\" complicated <String> />"
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: please open a bug for jruby.

Comment: => http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY

Comment: hey adam, did you get around creating an issue?

Comment: Please see [JRUBY-7121](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-7121)

Comment: Great, I created it here https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/561 (you need an account to create it in JIRA)

Comment: @AdamD: The bug [JRUBY-7121](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-7121) was closed two weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't create XML like this. Use Nokogiri or another XML library.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.node(:attr => 'this is "my" complicated <String>')
end

puts builder.to_xml
# prints: <node attr="this is &quot;my&quot; complicated &lt;String&gt;"/>
```

See also [Nokogiri::XML::Builder documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html)

Comment: I am using an XML builder for this (https://github.com/jimweirich/builder), but it wasn't performing the HTML escaping as I had hoped.  My example above is contrived, but what I'm trying to get at is why does JRuby perform differently than MRI for this task?

Comment: Alright then. I leave my answer as an example. I'd recommend to create a bug report, I was able to reproduce it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a JRuby bug. It has now been fixed in [master](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/pull/684) and should work in JRuby 1.7.4.